# Changing an object from an object inside of it

Tags: java, oop

If an object is inside of an object how do I manipulate the object it is inside of

Simple example of what I mean written below

How do I be able to make the mouse manipulate the cage variables (decrease cage strength).

```
public class Cage{
     public Cage(){
          cageStrength = 1;
          Mouse foo = new Mouse ();
          foo.eat();
     }
    public void changeCageStrength(){
        cageStrength--;
    }
}

}
```

```
public class Mouse{

     if(condition){
          eatPartOfCage();
      }
}
public void eatPartOfCage(){
     decrease cage strength;
}
```

Comment: To clear up a misconception: an object is never "inside" another object. Rather, an object can hold a reference to another object, which analogous to a person knowing somebody else's phone number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to establish a relationship beyond the fact that `Mouse foo` is a variable in a constructor of `Cage`. For example,

```
public class Cage {
    private Mouse foo;
    private int cageStrength;
    public Cage() {
        cageStrength = 1;
        foo = new Mouse(this);
    }
    public void changeCageStrength() {
        cageStrength--;
    }
}
```

And then your `Mouse foo` can invoke `Cage.changeCageStrength()` in `eat()` like

```
public class Mouse {
    private Cage cage;
    public Mouse(Cage cage) {
        this.cage = cage;
    }
    public void eat() {
        cage.changeCageStrength();
    }
}
```

Comment: Noting that irl it’s not up to the mouse to determine if it can alter the cage strength, rather a combination of the mouse and the cage (could be a brick cage, could be a mutant mouse with toll steel teeth).

Comment: @DaveNewton It could always be ["Slippery Jim" diGriz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stainless_Steel_Rat).